# Using UIScreen width property is breaking constraint of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to constraint `UITableViewCell` programmatically. My cell consists of a simple pager. My `init` method of cell includes following.

```
height =  UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.56 // If I use static i.e 320 value it is ok. 
width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width is ok.
pagerView.topAnchor.constrain(to: topAnchor)
pagerView.bottomAnchor.constrain(to: bottomAnchor)
pagerView.widthAnchor.constrain(to: width)
pagerView.heightAnchor.constrain(to: height)
```

When I try to constraint using `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` it gives me following error. However, if I use static 320 value instead of `UIScreen width` it is all good.

```
> 2020-02-25 16:07:44.209043+0300 myApp[23049:780168]
> [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>   Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
> you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to
> figure out which you don't expect;        (2) find the code that added the
> unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.  (
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035345f0 V:|-(0)-[FSPagerView.FSPagerView:0x7fb96c6226f0]   (active, names:
> '|':myApp.HomePagerCell:0x7fb96e041c00'HomePagerCell' )>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035346e0 FSPagerView.FSPagerView:0x7fb96c6226f0.bottom ==
> myApp.HomePagerCell:0x7fb96e041c00'HomePagerCell'.bottom   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003534780 FSPagerView.FSPagerView:0x7fb96c6226f0.height == 231.84   (active)>",
>     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003534aa0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height'
> myApp.HomePagerCell:0x7fb96e041c00'HomePagerCell'.height == 232  
> (active)>" ) Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
> <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003534780
> FSPagerView.FSPagerView:0x7fb96c6226f0.height == 231.84   (active)>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
> to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
> UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
> <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

What could be the reason of it and how can I solve it?

Comment: you cannot give ( top, bottom) and height constraint together. There will be a conflict. Either give top and bottom or top and height.

Comment: So, why there isn't any conflict when I tried to use static 320 value? @TejaNandamuri

Comment: the width constraint isnt the issue. The error log says the cell heigh constraint is conflicting.

Comment: Actually, when I added static 320 value for height it doesn't cause a break, too.

Comment: is there a reason you constrained both top and bottom and height ?

Comment: also what is the height of the cell you are returning in the heightForRow method ?

Comment: If your view contains something like a `textView`, and the `bounds.width` property is less than 320 points, than decreasing the `width` can cause the `height` to increase, and that's why you are getting height issues, so please consider removing one of the 3 constraints suggested above.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to autoresize my table view cell and the row height is `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`@TejaNandamuri

Comment: First, you shouldn't use `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` ... just constrain leading and trailing to the cell's `.contentView`. Second, constrain your `pagerView.heightAnchor` to `pagerView.widthtAnchor` with a `multiplier: 0.56`. Third, I believe it is common to get that layout conflict when using proportional values in cells... it usually can be fixed by setting the `priority` on that height constraint to `999`

Comment: Ok, now I understood my problem according to your answers. I should not have used  bottom and height constraints. @TejaNandamuri

Comment: am glad you figured it out @atalayasa